# Showing login errors using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I have this form :

```
        <form name="loginform" action="dologin.php" onsubmit="return isValid();" method="post">
            <span id="usr">Username:</span><input type="text" style="width:230px;margin-top:10px;" name="username" />
            <span id="psw">Password:</span><input type="password" style="width:230px;margin-top:10px;" name="password" />
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="button about small" style="width:100px;" />
            <a href="register.php">Click to Register!</a>
        </form>
```

And when someone enters the wrong password it will show an error (as expected).
I have this 'if' statement, `if($pass == $user['Password'])`.
And when it returns false it will show the error.
(Notice im only talking about the password validation, the form validation is in JS)

My question is how can I show the error? Make an empty span and then edit it (if it's possible)?

Comment: Please don't store passwords. Use hashes. https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: now where you are showing the error?

Comment: @Gourav I think that is what the question is about.

Comment: @GolezTrol And when someone enters the wrong password it will show an error (as expected). read this.

Comment: Yes, making an empty span and then edit it can be a way to do it, update it with php or js

Comment: I'm hashing the password into $pass = md5(strip_tags($_POST['password']));

Comment: you can update the error using php as well as JS.

Comment: How can I update the span through PHP, im doing the normal form validation through JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea.
 consider **login.php** is your login page with login form.

```
 <form name="loginform" action="dologin.php" onsubmit="return isValid();" method="post">
                <span id="usr">Username:</span><input type="text" style="width:230px;margin-top:10px;" name="username" />
                <span id="psw">Password:</span><input type="password" style="width:230px;margin-top:10px;" name="password" />
<?php if(isset($_GET['error1'])){?>
   <span style='color:#f00'>Passwor or username error</span>

<?php }?> 
                <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="button about small" style="width:100px;" />
                <a href="register.php">Click to Register!</a>

            </form>
```

And **login_sub.php** your sub page for check password.

```
  <?php
       //Chech username and password
      if($pass != $user['Password'])
           {?>
             <script>
                self.location='login.php?error1=1';
                </script>
       <?php}
     ?>
```

Comment: This is a pretty damn good idea, thank you!
I'll try to implement this into my code, and if it will work i'll mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

By using `PHP`

consider you are checking the login credentials. If user is not a valid user then store the error string in the variable `error`.

```
  $error="Invalid username/password";
```

Then you can include your login page on this page.

```
  include "login.php";
```

Then on `login.php`  page you put the below condition in a `span` or `div`

```
if(isset($error))
{
      echo $error;
}
```

your work is done.

Comment: Thank you too, tried your's first, didnt work, for sure something I did wrong, anyway's thank you!