# PHP Session getting data from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

i have the following code :

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="text1"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pwd"></td>


        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit1"></td>           

        </tr>
    </table>
</form>


</body>
</html>



<?php
include 'config.php';
mysql_select_db("sess_db",$con);

?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
      $result=mysql_query("SELECT username,password FROM siteinfo ");
      $result2=mysql_fetch_row($result);
      $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    $nm = $_POST['text1'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
    if ($result == $nm && $result == $pwd) {
        $_SESSION['luser'] = $name;
        $_SESSION['start'] = time();
        //the expire u put it
        $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (30 * 60);
        header('Location: homepage.php');
    }
    else {
        echo "Please Enter a Correct Username & Password ! ";
    }
}
?>
```

in the login page i must enter username : joseph and password : moon

but i want to remove this two variables `$name` & `$password` and link it to my database that contains usernames and passwords, if i enter one of them redirect me to the

> homepage.php

Comment: First add `session_start();` after your `<?php`

Comment: Your question shows that you don't know how to interact with a Database in PHP. You should read some documentation or tutorials first

Comment: i know how to connect it but the problem i don't know where must i put it @Tounu

Comment: before using the output

Comment: @Tounu i edited my question take a look and i'd to know where is the problem  !

Comment: @Joseph try to find some tutorials or something.There are plenty of them. You are doing things wrong !http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-login-form.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRy this. But it is too simple

```
     <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {

                $name = "Joseph";
                $password = "moon";
                $nm = $_POST['text1'];
                $con=myssql_connect('localhost','root','');// mysql_connect('your host name','database username','database password')
                mysql_select_db('your database name',$con) or die("Can't select DB");
                $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
                $qry="SELECT * FROM login_labe WHERE username='$name' AND 
password='$password'";
                $result=mysql_query($qry);
                $res=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                 $nm=$res['username'];
                 $pwd=$res['password'];
                if ($name == $nm && $password == $pwd) {
                    session_start();  ///////////////You need to add session_start()
                    $_SESSION['luser'] = $res['your name form DB'];
                    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
                    //the expire u put it
                    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (30 * 60);
                    header('Location: homepage.php');
                }
                else {
                    echo "Please Enter a Correct Username & Password ! ";
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: i added a session_start() at the top of my page ! 
what i want is how to connect with my db

Comment: You mean mysql php connection?

Comment: i want only the usernames and passwords that form my db to login if not show me > Please Enter a Correct Username & Password !
if you see in my code i removed  $name = "Joseph"; & $password = "moon"; ...

Comment: May be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441699/showing-login-errors-using-php/20441761#20441761

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add some filters on `$_POST['text1']` and `$_POST['pwd']`, to avoid injections in your SQL query, or unexpected behaviors.

```
$name = $_POST['text1'];
$pw = $_POST['pwd'];
```

Then, just build a query like this :

`SELECT count(*) from user_table where name = $name and pwd = $pw`

if `count != 0` then the association name/password is correct, and you can redirect the user to homepage.

This is very basic, you can do safer.